# Почему от освобождения переменной ломается вывод?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>


bool str(std::vector<char*>& vector)
{
    char* name = (char*)malloc(MAX_PATH);
    if (name != 0) { ZeroMemory(name, MAX_PATH); };
    lstrcatA(name, "Name: ");
    lstrcatA(name, "Anastasya");
    lstrcatA(name, "\nFNAME: ");
    lstrcatA(name, "Belkova");
    vector.push_back(name);
    free(name);
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<char*> name;
    str(name);
    std::cout << name[0];
}
```

Если я пишу в функции `str` `free(name)` у меня вывод в консоли примерно такой

```
▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌
```

А если я убираю `free(name)` то выводит всё как надо. В чем ошибка и что я упустил?

Comment: Вектор хранит только указатели, а память, на которую они указывают, Вы освобождаете.

Comment: WinAPI + C-память + вектор -- моё почтение

Comment: А обращение к памяти после освобождения - это всегда UB. Автору вопроса ещё повезло, что он увидел палочки. А мог креш получить или формат диска.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что указатели хранят только адрес. Вы выделяете память с помощью `malloc` и сохраняете адрес этой памяти в указателе в векторе и сразу освобождаете эту память. В результате в векторе находится указатель на память, которой Ваша программа уже не владеет. На момент вывода, этой памятью уже могла пользоваться другая программа, которая изменила её содержимое, что Вы и наблюдаете. В С++ есть класс `std::string`, который предназначен для работы со строками. Используйте его.